# Itext PDF Shrink issue with hyperlink bounding box is not getting Shrinked

Tags: java, hyperlink, itext, pdf-generation, bounding-box

I am working with PDF shrinking and then watermarking it and for the same I am using itextpdf-5.5.1.jar.  Here is the code which I use to shrink PDF. In code xPercentage and xPercentage value is 0.9f. When I shrink PDF having content table , content on the page is shrinking properly. When I go to table of content the bounding box of hyperlink is getting misplaced.  I noticed that size of bounding box is same for Original and shrink output document.  How do I shrink bounding box of hyperlink with respect to content?

```
public  void shrinkPDF(String strFilePath , String strFileName) throws Exception{
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(strFilePath+"//"+strFileName);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new 
FileOutputStream(strFilePath+"//Shrink_"+strFileName));
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
Map mpPDFLayer = stamper.getPdfLayers();
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        float offsetX = (reader.getPageSize(p).getWidth() * (1 - xPercentage)) / 2;
        float offsetY = (reader.getPageSize(p).getHeight() * (1 - yPercentage)) / 2;
        stamper.getUnderContent(p).setLiteral(
                    String.format("\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n",
                    xPercentage, yPercentage, offsetX, offsetY));

        stamper.getOverContent(p).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    }   
stamper.close();
reader.close();
}
```

Comment: does my answer sufficiently answer your question? If not, why don't you ask for clarifications or more details. Otherwise, why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Apologies, new to stackoverflow. Thanks for reminding. I am working on annotations to resolve this issue. However I am having another issue related to Orientation for same code. I have raised another question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shrinks only the content but it does not accordingly move and shrink annotations. So what you have to do additionally is to iterate over the annotations of each page and shrink them.

This in particular means that you have to shrink and move the **Rect** annotation rectangle. Depending on the nature of the respective annotation, though, there also are other coordinate values in them, e.g. the **QuadPoints** in case of a link or the **L** endpoint coordinates of a line.

---

BTW, your content shrinking code makes assumptions on the origin of the user space coordinate system; it appears to assume that the origin is in the lower left of the crop box and that the crop box and the media box coincide.